# How to make pandas replace work like python default replace

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a csv that has a column called 'ra'.

This is the first 'ra' value the csv has: 8570.0 - I will use it as an example.

I need to remove '.0'.

So I've tried:

```
dtypes = {

'ra': 'str',

}

df['ra_csv'] = pd.DataFrame({'ra_csv':df['ra']}).replace('.0', '', regex=true).astype(str)
```

This code returns me '85' instead of '8570'. It's replacing all the 0s, and somehow removed the number '7' aswell.

How can I make it return '8750'? Thanks.

Comment: @Ch3steR, regex=False returns '8570.0', it doesnt replace '.0'.

Comment: check dtype? its a float or a string? too many question marks without a proper reproducible example.

Comment: @anky, it's a string.

Comment: @fsimoes Please add your dataframe to the question. You can [edit] your question from here. And what's the output of `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: Not sure if all the rows have valid data but based on sample df, using `to_numeric` might be more appropriate here, pd.to_numeric(df['ra_csv']).astype(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: use to_numeric to first convert the data to numeric type and convert to int,

```
df['ra_csv'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ra_csv']).astype(int)
```

Option 2: using `str.replace`

```
df['ra_csv'] = df['ra_csv'].str.replace('\..*', '')
```

You get

```
    ra_csv
0   8570
```

Answer (score 1):

The *regex* pattern `.0` has two matches in your string `'8570.0'`. `.` matches any character.

- `70`
- `.0`

Since you are using `df.replace` setting `regex=False` wouldn't because it checks for exact matches only.
From docs [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

> str: string exactly matching to_replace will be replaced with value

Possible fixes are either fix your regex or use [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

- Fixing your regex

  ```
  df.replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
  ```
- Using `str.replace`

  ```
  df['ra'].str.replace('.0', '', regex=False)
  ```